# Laravel send email partially working

Tags: php, email, laravel-5

I created a simple email send in my Laravel application for notifing users on some events.
In my .env I have:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=my.host.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=my.email@mydomain.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=mypassword
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

I use Mail::send() for sending email. Most of the emails get through normally (they don't go to spam). I have a problem with one specific email. I was wondering if there is a simple way to check the response from the email server of the problematic email? Where can I start searching? Is there any way I can find out what the problem is without contacting the domain administrators? Or perhaps a pointer on what I can try? BR, Igor

Comment: Do you use Mail queueing? Is there an exception with the failing email?

Comment: No I don't use queueing. Not sending that many emails. But thank you for the heads up. I will look out for that in the future as I plan to implement bulk notifications on another task.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. I was using an alias for sending emails from the application and I guess some email filters don't allow that.